Ignore warnings in R shapiro.test package = stats
I have to run Shapiro-Wilk Tests in R on some not very good data...
Because I have data with the same 3 values for stations (OF and EX) the shapiro.test (package = stats) is returning this error
"Error in shapiro.test(df$Value[df$STATION == "EX"]) :
all 'x' values are identical"
Is there anyway to override this error??
example data
df = structure(list(STATION = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("EX", "OF", "RE"), class = "factor"), 
    Variable = c("pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", 
    "pH"), Value = c(8.3, 8.2, 8.2, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 8.2, 8.2, 
    8.2)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Example code
shap.t.result = shapiro.test(df$Value[df$STATION == "EX"])




The error message is there for a reason. If all observations have the same value, the mean is equal to that value. In other words, there is no variation in the data.

You can't override the error, but you can catch it (and prevent it from stopping your code) by running the function with try()
shap.t.result <- try(shapiro.test(df$Value[df$STATION == "EX"]))

If the test fails, you will get an object of class try-error rather than an htest test result.  You could also do something like this:
my_shap_test <- purrr::safely(function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value,
                        otherwise = NA_real_)
my_shap_test(df$Value[df$STATION == "EX"])$result  ## NA

